# What is the shortest and cleanest way to recode multiple variables in a dataframe using R?

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

So I'm working in the field of social science and what I often have to do is to manipulate multiple variables to change values. More often than not this means to reverse a scale. I've been working with *SPSS* for a long time and the syntax there is quite simple. To change the values of multiple variables you write:

`RECODE var1 var2 var3 (1=5) (2=4) 4=2) (5=1) (ELSE=COPY).`

To write the new codes in new variables you add `into newvar1 newvar1 newvar3.` at the end. In the brackets you can use things like `hi`, `lo`, `1 to 4` and so on.

Now I'm working my way into *R* and I'm struggeling to find the best way to do similar workflows. I found the following solutions, but can't get a short nice way:

```
## Packages -----
library(dplyr)
library(car)

## Data -----
tib <- tibble(v1 = 1:4, 
              v2 = 1:4,
              v3 = sample(1:5, 4, replace = FALSE))

vars <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
```

The base way:

```
tib$v2_rec <- NA
tib$v2_rec[tib$v2 == 1] <- 5 #1
tib$v2_rec[tib$v2 == 2] <- 4 #2
tib$v2_rec[tib$v2 == 3] <- 3 #3
tib$v2_rec[tib$v2 == 4] <- 2 #4
tib$v2_rec[tib$v2 == 5] <- 1 #5
# I'm forced to create a new variable here, otherwise #4 and #5 overwrite #1 and #2.
# Therefore I won't even bother to try to loop trough multiple variables.
```

recode() from the package car:

```
tib$v1 <- recode(tib$v1, "1=5; 2=4; 4=2; 5=1")
# This is nice, understandable and short
# To handle multiple variables the following solutions won't work, because the reload functions seems not to be able to iterate through lists:

tib[vars] <- recode(tib[vars], "1=5; 2=4; 4=2; 5=1")
tib[1:3] <- recode(tib[1:3], "1=5; 2=4; 4=2; 5=1")

# I'd be forced to loop:

for (i in vars) {
  tib[[i]] <- recode(tib[[i]], "1=5; 2=4; 4=2; 5=1")
}
```

I'm pretty happy with that but I was wondering if there's a function that would do the work of looping for me. I'm realy struggling with the dplyer functions at the moment and I'm not happy how I can't figure things out intuitively...

I tried mutate:

```
#I get it for a single case and for multiple cases i got to a solution in combination with the recode() function:

tib <- tib %>%
  mutate_at(vars(v1:v3), 
            function(x) recode(x, "1=5; 2=4; 4=2; 5=1"))
```

Is this the best way to do this? Just to be clear, I saw some other solutions using case_when(), replace() or mapvalues() but I find the solution above better, because I like to see what value gets recoded to what value in one glimps.

I got a little into the apply() function and could not even recode one variable with it. I'm sure I'll get a grip on that as well soon, but at the moment I'm just a little frustrated how long I'm looking around for workflows that took me one line in SPSS. If you know any shorter and cleaner solution than the one above using the apply() function I would be greatful!

I'm happy with R and it's possibilities but right now I need a hint in the right direction to keep me going! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if used correctly, `dplyr` has the "cleanest" syntax in this case:

```
library(dplyr)
tib <- tibble(v1 = 1:4, 
              v2 = 1:4,
              v3 = sample(1:5, 4, replace = FALSE))

tib %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(v1:v3), recode, `1` = 5, `2` = 4, `3` = 3, `4` = 2, `5` = 1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      v1    v2    v3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     5     5     2
#> 2     4     4     5
#> 3     3     3     4
#> 4     2     2     1
```

Note that I had to add `3 = 3` because recode needs a replacement for all values.

I often find it easier to write things more explicitly with functions that are new to me, so maybe this might help:

```
tib %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(v1:v3), 
            .funs = function(x) recode(x, 
                                       `1` = 5, 
                                       `2` = 4, 
                                       `3` = 3, 
                                       `4` = 2, 
                                       `5` = 1))
```

If you prefer the `recode` function from `car` you should not load `car` but use:

```
tib %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(v1:v3), car::recode, "1=5; 2=4; 4=2; 5=1")
```

That way you don't run into trouble mixing `dplyr` with `car` (as long as you don't need `car` for anything else.

Comment: This is pretty clean, thank you very much! I don't like the notation with ` though... I'm getting into trouble with to functions called recode() at the moment. But I guess it's a good idea to go dplyr all the way.

Comment: I see now, so the "function(x)" is not really needed! Even better now: `tib <- tib %>%
  mutate_at(vars(v1:v3), recode , "1=5; 2=4; 4=2; 5=1")`

Comment: I think you'll run into problems with the two `recode` functions in this case (it didn't work for me). Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. At the moment I only know car because of the recode function. I think I'll do it the way you suggested!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way using only base functions.  This assumes that these are 5-point likert items where the original coding was 1 - 5.  If you had, say, 7-point likert items, or coded 0 - 4, or -2 - 2, you'd need to adapt this.

Some coding notes: You have a pseudorandom generation element to your dataset (the call to `sample()`); to make the dataset exactly reproducible, use [?set.seed](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html).  You can automatically print a variable or dataset that has been assigned by enclosing it in parentheses when using the arrow assignment operator (`(var <- value)`).  R is vectorized, so you don't need a loop (although it's really OK here--with so few variables it won't cause a noticeable slowdown).

```
set.seed(4636)  # this makes the example exactly reproducible
(d <- data.frame(v1 = 1:4, 
                 v2 = 1:4,
                 v3 = sample(1:5, 4, replace = FALSE)))  # adding outer ()'s prints
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  1  1  1
# 2  2  2  2
# 3  3  3  5
# 4  4  4  4

d.orig <- d  # here's your original dataset, so they aren't overwritten
(d <- 6-d)  # adding outer ()'s prints
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  5  5  5
# 2  4  4  4
# 3  3  3  1
# 4  2  2  2

rec.vars <- c("v2")
d.some   <- d.orig
(d.some[,rec.vars] <- 6-d.some[,rec.vars])
# [1] 5 4 3 2
d.some
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  1  5  1
# 2  2  4  2
# 3  3  3  5
# 4  4  2  4

##### to do more than 1 variable
(rec.vars <- paste0("v", c(2,3)))
# [1] "v2" "v3"
d.some   <- d.orig
(d.some[,rec.vars] <- 6-d.some[,rec.vars])
#   v2 v3
# 1  5  5
# 2  4  4
# 3  3  1
# 4  2  2
d.some
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  1  5  5
# 2  2  4  4
# 3  3  3  1
# 4  4  2  2
```

Comment: Nice solution. The question is if `6-d` is a coincidence or this is the recoding that's usually needed.

Comment: @JBGruber, you're right.  I was adding that to the answer.

Comment: Thank your for your response! What I don't like is that it's not that obvious what's happening in the code, but I'm surprised that I never thought of that way to recode (6-x). If I would comment the code this could be the best way in certain cases. I'll keep that solution in mind.

Comment: @2freet, my intention is for the code to be almost self-explanatory.  Note also that I did add some comments.  It would help me if you could be more specific about what you don't understand, so that I could avoid that in the future; I could also add more exposition & comments here.

Comment: @gung, Don't get me wrong, I understand the code. What I meant is that I can't see in a split second where the recoding is going on and what happens to a 4 in the data set. You know what I mean? If I get a strange result in in analysis step later and I want to check if I made an error regarding recoding or if there even was recoding, it is easier to spot it in some scripts than in others.

Comment: @gung, I run checks as well but it proved to be usefull working multiple times with the same syntax, or when working in a team. Crosschecking stuff etc. is simpler that way.